# Efficiently Computing a Non-negative Solution for an Underdetermined System of Linear Equations with 0-1 Coefficient Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, linear-diophantine-equations

I have a system of linear diophantine equations having $m$ constraints and $n$ variables, where $n>>m$. The coefficient matrix has all entries either 0 or 1. I am interested in finding a non-negative solution to this system *very efficiently*. An approximate solution that satisfies the constraints with bounded error will also do. Any pointers to this problem would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the linear system is $Ax=b$.  You can solve the problem via mixed integer linear programming, as follows.  For each constraint $i$, introduce nonnegative surplus and slack variables $s_i$ and $t_i$, respectively.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_i (s_i+t_i)$ subject to
\begin{align}
Ax-s+t&=b \\
x &\ge 0 \text{ integer}\\
s &\ge 0\\
t &\ge 0
\end{align}
As usual with mixed integer linear programming, the linear programming relaxation provides a lower bound.  This formulation does not depend on the entries $A$ being 0-1.

Comment: I am not sure if this can scale to very large number of variables (say in billions). What I am interested in is that algorithm is scalable to large number of variables although a bounded error on accuracy wrt satisfiability of each constraint is tolerable.

Comment: Are most variables nonzero in a feasible solution? If not, you might consider *column generation*, which works with a small subset of them at a time and introduces new ones dynamically as needed.

Comment: Since number of variables is much more than the number of constraints, a basic feasible solution would have most of the variables being zero. However, in general, there can be other feasible solutions that have many nonzero variables. I am not familiar with column generation algorithm, I'd look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry if my doubt is trivial, but I was wondering that to apply techniques like column generation, we do have to start with a basic feasible solution, right? In my case, all I care about is to find a feasible solution and there is no optimization function in particular. We need to find a feasible solution quickly or even a solution with bounded error.

Comment: You can start with $x=0$, $s=\max(-b,0)$, $t=\max(b,0)$.

Comment: I read about column generation using the cutting stock problem. So in that problem the columns have a nice property that needs to be satisfied which makes it easier to generate the column. For a general set of equations, generating the column may not be as obvious right? So basically what I am trying to ask is the column generation is not applicable to all sorts of problems right? The columns need to have a nice property that can be expressed as a system of constraints and also any column that satisfies those constraints, qualifies to be a column, right?

Comment: Column generation is a general technique, but its performance usually relies on exploiting structure, like in the cutting stock problem.  What does your original problem look like?

Comment: Let me explain it using an example. Say I've a large number of buckets. We want to assign certain number of balls to each bucket. Each bucket has a set of properties associated with it like color, bucket number etc. We're given some constraints like - the number of balls assigned to all red colored buckets should sum up to 1000; or the total balls present in all green and even numbered buckets is 500. We want to compute an assignment of balls to the buckets such that all constraints are satisfied.

Comment: So if we create a variable for each bucket indicating its assignment, we need a non negative integral solution to the variables such that all the constraints (always equality) are satisfied and the coefficient matrix has 0s and 1s only (indicating the inclusion or exclusion of a bucket for a given constraint).

Comment: OK, it sounds like you have one column per bucket. To use column generation, you need to be able to describe what defines a bucket: number of balls, bucket color, bucket number, and what else?

Comment: I was just giving an example. You can assume there are several features associated. Number of balls is not a feature but a variable that you have to calculate such that the constraints are satisfied. Constraints would be like sum of number of balls is equal to a given constant for the buckets where one or more features have some condition satisfied. You are right that we associate a column per bucket. For example purposes you can assume bucket features like bucket number, color, size (small, medium, large), price, seller name etc.